# Get First Search Result from google

Tags: powershell, scrape, web-content

I am currently attempting to use Powershell to scrape link pages from a specific site.  Have knocked up a variation of the current code but it is essential the same.

I am attempting to get the URL for the search google search result. I have added the below screenshot to explain what i am hoping to grab.

[image]

I so far have the following code which is converting the text to a successful search and is working as expected.however when called with the Invoke-WebRequest i dont get any meaningful results. when using a browser with the link it works sucsessfully

```
function Get-GoogleSEQueryString 
{
    param([string[]] $Query)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web # To get UrlEncode()
    $QueryString = ($Query | %{ [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_)}) -join '+'

    # Return the query string
    $QueryString
}

$SearchString = "Requiem for an American Dream"
$QueryString = Get-GoogleSEQueryString $SearchString
$url = "http://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZuzTV_v6B7Du8weC8qsY#q="+$QueryString+"+site:IMDB.com"

#(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url).links | Where-Object {$_.href -like "http*"}

$t = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url
$t.AllElements | Where {$_.innerhtml -like '*=*'} |Sort { $_.InnerHtml.Length } | Out-GridView
```

Can anyone kindly assist in regards to this problem?

Comment: You don't actually say what the problem is? _however when called with the Invoke-WebRequest_.....

Comment: Google page is dynamically populated so the response doesn't contain anything useful, you'll need to use InternetExplorer.Application, there are many examples of doing that. Or switch to a different search engine with an API.

Comment: you might wanna have a look at Microsoft Cognitive Services 
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/apis

Comment: or alternatively you might examine the actual request sequence in smth like Fiddler and reproduce it in PoSh /with all the headers, UA etc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments as an answer, Google's main search page doesn't contain the search result in the HTML. It only has some containers and will load it during the page load and populate the HTML DOM dynamically.

When you download the page you only get the container HTML without the results. You can actually see the same if you select 'View source' on the Google search result page.

You can try other search engines or use web services to fetch the data.

You can learn more about Google's web service here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list